# Force LDR instruction to place value in literal pool in THUMB assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler, thumb, devkitpro

I'm trying to create a matching GBA disassembly using devkitpro, and I'm having trouble with the THUMB instruction `LDR R1, =0x3FF`.

I want it to place `0x3FF` in the literal pool and generate a PC-relative address, which is what the assembled version does, however it insists on creating a `MOVW` 32-bit instruction instead.

I've tried using the length specifier `LDR.N` to force it to generate a 16-bit instruction, however this appears to have made no difference at all.

While I could just use the PC-relative address directly, since this is in the middle of the literal pool it would cause me to have to delete a large amount of the pool and implement the loads in the same way, which would be very messy, so this is only a last resort. If anyone knows some way I could force this instruction to generate a PC-relative address that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Which assembler is this?  Have you tried setting the CPU type to the one used in the GBA?

Comment: I'm using the assembler built into devkitpro which I believe is the GNU assembler, its program name is `arm-none-eabi-as`. I haven't tried setting the CPU type, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Arthur Tilly: As you are a new user, I would suggest reading this article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time you ask a question since this will make easier for people to help you.

I may have misunderstood your question, but I am not getting any `movw` instruction in the code assembled from the following program - you may just have specified the wrong cpu for the [GBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Advance), or you may be using the default cpu which is unlikely to be `arm7tdmi`, since it was introduced in 1994.

`ldr.s`:

```
.cpu arm7tdmi
.thumb
ldr r1, =0x3ff
.end

/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -c ldr.s
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d a.out 

a.out:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4900            ldr     r1, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <.text+0x4>)
   2:   0000            .short  0x0000
   4:   000003ff        .word   0x000003ff
```

Setting the cpu , say, to `cortex-m3`, does provide an output consistent with what you are describing:

`ldr.s`:

```
    .cpu cortex-m3
    .thumb
    ldr r1, =0x3ff
    .end

    /opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -c ldr.s
    /opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -d a.out 
    
    a.out:     file format elf32-littlearm
    
    
    Disassembly of section .text:
    
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f240 31ff       movw    r1, #1023       ; 0x3ff
```